# How to set a maximum width of a layout/view in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, layout, xamarin.forms

I have a signup page with a few labels and entries, it works fine in portrait, but when in landscape, especially in the UWP, the entries takes the width of the whole screen.

Is there a way to set the layout/view not to exceed a certain width?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured it out, the `WidthRequest" will try to get the requested width, if not it will take the width available by the parent item. So basically, we do not need a maximum width property.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the SizeChanged event of the Page to customize the layout when switching to/from portrait/landscape mode :

```
public partial class MyPage : ContentPage
{
    public MyPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        SizeChanged += OnSizeChanged;
    }

    void OnSizeChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Customize your layout here (i.e. using HeightRequest/WidthRequest)...
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

You can use **WidthRequest** and **HeightRequest** or LayoutOptions(**HorizontalOptions** and **VerticalOptions**) for better positioning of views inside Layout

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to set Maximum Width property. You would try something like that:

```
<Grid BackgroundColor="Black Padding="10,10,0,10" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <Button Text="XXX" 
            Command="{Binding SignUpCommand}" 
            WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="70"
            Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Style="{StaticResource GrayButton} " / >
```

this would help to fit exactly your HeightRequest and WidthRequest.